# Expo Location, get and send coordinate

Tags: react-native, google-maps

i am trying to get expo location to display my location in mapview,
one button to get coordinates
and another button to send the coordinates.

the job is to display location on mapview, a button toget and display the coordinates and a button to send those coordinates.

this code here https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/location/ only displays the cordinates.
below is my present state:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';



const Cordinate = ({ navigation }) => {
  //navigator
  const popHandler = () => {
    navigation.pop();
  };
  const pushHandler = () => {
    navigation.push("Field officer's note");
  };
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.camera}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          region={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}         
        >
            <Marker
          coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324}}
          title="this is a marker"
          description="this is a marker example"
        />
        </MapView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>latitude </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>longitude</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btLogin1} >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText1}>Get coordinates</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btLogin1} >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText1}>Send coordinates</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  camera: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    aspectRatio: 0.868,
    flex: 0.8,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    color: "#000",
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "#3675B8",
    marginTop: 6,
  },
  buttonText1: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#fff",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#000",
  },
  btLogin: {
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    height: 37,
    backgroundColor: "#3675B8",
    padding: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 12,
    width: "46.5%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  btLogin1: {
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    height: 37,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#3675B8",
    padding: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
    width: "67%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  TextInput: {
    height: 30,
    marginTop: 6,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "#3675B8",
    backgroundColor: "#eff9f8",
    marginHorizontal: 6,
    width: "52%",
  },
});

export default Cordinate;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code where I used the Location from the expo-location from your code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';



const Cordinate = ({ navigation }) => {
  //navigator
  const popHandler = () => {
    navigation.pop();
  };
  const pushHandler = () => {
    navigation.push("Field officer's note");
  };
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [region,setRegion]=useState({
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }

  )


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);



const getLoc =() =>{
  //console.log("press",location.coords)
  let latitude= location.coords.latitude
  let longitude=location.coords.longitude
  setRegion({
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          })
}

const sendLoc =() =>{
  
  let latitude= location.coords.latitude
  let longitude=location.coords.longitude
console.log("Use these variables to send current location(",latitude, ",",longitude,")")
}


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.camera}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          region={region}         
        >
            <Marker
          coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324}}
          title="this is a marker"
          description="this is a marker example"
        />
        </MapView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>latitude </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput}> {region.latitude}</TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>longitude</Text>
       <TextInput style={styles.TextInput}> {region.longitude}</TextInput>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btLogin1}  onPress={getLoc} >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText1}>Get coordinates</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btLogin1} onPress={sendLoc}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText1}>Send coordinates</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  camera: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    aspectRatio: 0.868,
    flex: 0.8,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    color: "#000",
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "#3675B8",
    marginTop: 6,
  },
  buttonText1: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#fff",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#000",
  },
  btLogin: {
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    height: 37,
    backgroundColor: "#3675B8",
    padding: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 12,
    width: "46.5%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  btLogin1: {
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    height: 37,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#3675B8",
    padding: 7,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 12,
    width: "67%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  TextInput: {
    height: 30,
    marginTop: 6,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: "#3675B8",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderBottomColor: "#3675B8",
    backgroundColor: "#eff9f8",
    marginHorizontal: 6,
    width: "52%",
  },
});

export default Cordinate;
```